# strstr doesn't work with the delimiter "\r\n\r\n"

Tags: c, newline, strstr

i got the delimiter "\r\n\r\n" in the substring, and strstr is returning null

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int ac, char **av) {
  char *ptr;

  ptr = strstr(av[1], "\r\n\r\n");
  printf("ptr = %s\n", ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I launch the code with this :

```
./a.out "POST /cgi-bin/process.cgi HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)\nHost: www.tutorialspoint.com\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\nContent-Length: length\nAccept-Language: en-us\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
```

And ptr is equal to (null), why ?

Comment: Removed my comment, the guys are correct: backslashes need to be escaped.

Comment: `strstr()` returns `NULL` when it doesn't find the searched string.  You can look that in the manual page of `strstr()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you passed to the code contains the eight character sequence `\`, `r`, `\`, `n`,  `\`, `r`, `\`, `n`.

The string literal `"\r\n\r\n"` produces the four character  sequence `␍`, `␊`, `␍`, `␊`.

---

To produce a string that would match the argument, use the following string literal:

```c
"\\r\\n\\r\\n"
```

But I think it's more likely you want to providing a proper HTTP request.

Depending on which `echo` you use, `echo` or `echo -e` might produce the desired string (plus a trailing line feed):

```
$ echo -e 'a\r\nb\r\n' | od -c
0000000   a  \r  \n   b  \r  \n  \n
0000007
```

`printf` can reliably produce exactly the string you want, though you have to escape `%` symbols by duplicating them.

```
$ printf 'a\r\n%%\r\n' | od -c
0000000   a  \r  \n   %  \r  \n
0000006
```

Example usage:

```sh
./a.out "$( printf 'POST ...\r\n\r\n...' )"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to use `strstr(av[1], "\\r\\n\\r\\n")`

Comment: That is not what is intented. The problem is how to provide a string via command line that contains cr and lf.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use bash $'string' quoting:

```
$ ./a.out $'POST /cgi-bin/process.cgi HTTP/1.1\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)\nHost: www.tutorialspoint.com\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\nContent-Length: length\nAccept-Language: en-us\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>'
```